# jsonp script tag with parameters

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Hi all I'm trying to do an API call using a jsonp setup with a script tag but not sure how to pass it a function as one of the parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/proxy.cfm?apicall=news&pageid="+utils.stringToJson(cookie.read('current_stb')).pageid+"&callback='mynamespace.pagesCallback'"></script>
```

Can I add this right into the string like this.
+utils.stringToJson(cookie.read('current_stb')).pageid+

Or is their a way for me to pass it as a variable.

**I update the script based on Martins comments below.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="script"></script>
<script>
    $("#script").attr('href', "/proxy.cfm?apicall=news&pageid="+utils.stringToJson(cookie.read('current_stb')).pageid+"&callback="mynamespace.pagesCallback);
</script>
```

Now I'm getting a error missing ) after argument list but I'm not seeing where I left out a )

Comment: You can't do it that way. HTML does not know about JavaScript and cannot execute it. You have to create the element or set the attribute programmatically.  But as you are using jQuery, you can simply use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an attribute `src` to the script

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="script"></script>

<script>
$("#script").attr('src', "/proxy.cfm?apicall=news&pageid="+utils.stringToJson(cookie.read('current_stb')).pageid+"&callback="+mynamespace.pagesCallback);
</script>
```

Comment: @Chapsterj: it's id of that `<script>` tag

Comment: Thanks martin. When I use what you have I get error. missing ) after argument list

Comment: Thanks Martin its no longer giving an error but the callBack does not get called.

Comment: do I need to add a type to the string for GET

Comment: @Chapsterj: it depends on everything.